# submit after 5 sec on enter, javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to submit input details by clicking enter but in 5 sec here is the code please add timing in the code

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    inputValue.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code === "Enter") 
      {
        let input = inputValue.value;
        inputValue.value = "";
        output(input);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: You can try sleep or setTimeout

Comment: You want that user press por 5 seconds long, or that the submit happens 5s after any press duration?

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    inputValue.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code === "Enter") 
      {
       setTimeout(()=>{
        let input = inputValue.value;
        inputValue.value = "";
        output(input);
       }, 5000)
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(_=>{
    if (e.code === "Enter") 
      {
        let input = inputValue.value;
        inputValue.value = "";
        output(input);
      }
} 
, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    inputValue.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code === "Enter") 
      {
      var timer = setTimeout(()=>{
           let input = inputValue.value;
            inputValue.value = "";
            output(input);
          }, 5000)
        
      }
    });
  });
```